# Mí pregunta es la ¿por qué al realizar un onclick, pero al ejecutarlo, se refresca la pantalla y no conserva el innerHTML?

Tags: inner

Al agregar un onclick en un botón, se refresca todo y no me conserva lo que quiero ver en pantalla con el innerHTML, si alguien me podría ayudar, se los agradezco.

EN JAVASCRIPT

```
function recibir(){
        
        let cantidad=document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
        
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML=cantidad;
}
```

Comment: tienes que poner el codigo completo

Comment: Si es el botón de enviar de un formulario, al mandar un formulario por POST o GET la págona se actualiza para enviar esos datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues, debes decirle a tu acción que no avance al servidor.

**Primera forma:**

```
onClick="recibir(); return false()"
```

**Segunda forma:**

```
function recibir(){
  let cantidad=document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML=cantidad;
  return false;
}
```